# The menu item isn't showing in the ActionBar, only in overflow menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overflow-menu

I have exactly the same problem as in these threads:

[No actions or icons showing on the actionbar; only in overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365135/no-actions-or-icons-showing-on-the-actionbar-only-in-overflow)

[Menu items won't show up in the actiobar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479255/menu-items-wont-show-up-in-the-actiobar)

No one has offered a solution, so I want to bring it up again.

I have a xml-file, my_menu.xml, that look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_image"
        android:title="delete"/>
</menu>
```

My activity extends ActionBarActivity and implements these methods:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
            return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch(item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.delete:
                    //delete something
                    break;
            }

            return(true);
}
```

In my book: "A value of ifRoom means that the menu item will appear in the action bar if there is space for it" - I have tested to use ifRoom, ifRoom|withText and always, but the item always ends up in the overflow menu. I have tested the application on different devices, and it's plenty of room. Do anyone have a solution to this?

Hank

Comment: Are you using support library by any chance?

Comment: No, but I'm running the application in GenyMotion.

Comment: is `android:showAsAction="always"` not working for you?

Comment: No, it isn't working...

Comment: how many items do you have with `always` or before that particular menu item with `ifRoom` ?

Comment: That is my only item.

Comment: is the device screen large enough to display it in action bar?

Comment: Yes, it is. I've tried on several devices with different sizes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My activity extends ActionBarActivity

As is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems), if you are using the `appcompat_v7` backport of the action bar, and its associated `ActionBarActivity`, your menu resource needs to have `showAsAction` in a namespace custom to your app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_image"
        android:title="delete"/>
</menu>
```

[Here is a complete sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/AppCompat) demonstrating the use of the `appcompat_v7` action bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_image"
        android:title="delete"/>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: `always` on its own should work too. There must be a different reason.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help :/